# Return 401 Unauthorized when use Graph API to read calendar and mailbox setting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have setup a work account on Azure and add permissions **"User.ReadBasic.All",     "MailboxSettings.Read", "Calendars.ReadBasic.All"** with application type

1. I can use client credential flow to get the access token successfully

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

the token can be parsed by https://jwt.ms with proper role

> "roles": [
> "User.ReadBasic.All",
> "MailboxSettings.Read",
> "Calendars.ReadBasic.All"   ]

2. I can query user information successfully using the token

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}
```

3. But it returns error 401 when query calendar or mailboxSettings

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/calendar/calendarView?startdatetime=2021-12-23T08%3A00%3A00.000Z&enddatetime=2022-12-23T18%3A00%3A00.000Z

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/mailboxSettings
```

Both return error below

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "UnknownError",
> "message": "",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2023-01-05T11:06:14",
> "request-id": "xxx",
> "client-request-id": "xxxx"
> }
> } }

4. Is "MailboxSettings.Read" and "Calendars.ReadBasic.All" enough for the above query, or need more permissions like **Calendars.Read / Calendars.ReadWrite / MailboxSettings.ReadWrite** ?
5. Also for permission of calendar, which one is a higher permission, is the below correct?

Calendars.Read < Calendars.ReadBasic.All

Comment: Let's see the [api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) for corresponding graph api.

Comment: And `MailboxSettings.Read` should be enough for getting mailbox setting according to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), so you may try to add `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` and test again.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. 
Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Comment: It still failed even granted all below: Calendars.ReadBasic.All, Calendars.Read, MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite, User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try by providing user.ReadAll permission instead of User.ReadBasic.All

Comment: It still failed even granted all below: Calendars.ReadBasic.All, Calendars.Read, MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite, User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All

Comment: Are you trying this for guest users?

Comment: I plan to implement a backed API to retrieve these data using MS Graph API